# Is Access Database enough for storing Invoices

Tags: forms, ms-access, invoice

I'm making windows forms where I will enter and edit invoices for construction (Tables for Invoices,Buyer Info, Description(several) etc.)  I'm planning on storing them in an Access Database 2003, so I was wondering will it be enough for 10.000 invoices, at least?

Comment: There are products on the market which are built to do exactly this - why reinvent the wheel (before you say "but those cost money!", consider how much your time is worth)? Capacity-wise, Access can probably handle it. But when it comes to stability & integrity for a business-critical function, I'd look elsewhere.

Comment: You're not going to hit capacity limits, but there are other applicable limitations -- reliability, scalability, multi-user connection support, replication, etc. Access is not the right tool for anything important.

Comment: @alroc Products like databases or whole applications? Can you name some of these products? Thanks

Comment: Invoicing applications. Quickbooks, Freshbooks, there must be at least a dozen on the market. Unless you have a very specific business need which none of those can fulfill, you're better off buying something than building it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access can definitely handle 10k rows in the invoices table and let's say 100k in the details table. The report designer is really cool but if you don't need that I would go with SQL express or similar just to avoid a whole lot of headaches + no need for office on user's machine.

Comment: The SQL Express, can it be used offline? Let's say I implement it in a winform and use it on another computer without a server or visual studio?

Comment: Do I need to have something installed when I run the exe file from the project's debug folder?